# conditions formation for two colums

Tags: excel, vba

How can I make the two columns to meet both the conditions then highlight it red? right now is either columns met the condition then it will highlight red.

```
         If InStr(rcol.Value, "L-Start") > 0 Then
                        With rcol.EntireColumn.Cells
                        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=(today() - 120)"
                        With .FormatConditions(1).Font
                            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        End With
                    End With
                    End If

                If InStr(rcol.Value, "L-Type") > 0 Then
                    With rcol.EntireColumn.Cells
                        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""Q"""

                        With .FormatConditions(1).Font
                            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        End With
                    End With
                End If
```

Comment: Use AND to check both conditions in the same IF:   `If InStr(rcol.Value, "L-Start") > 0 And InStr(rcol.Value, "L-Type") > 0 Then`. It does more than just highlight red so I can't help more since it's poorly explained.

Comment: Are you wanting to only highlight the columns if both are true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will only paint the cells red if both conditions are met

```
            If InStr(rcol.Value, "L-Start") > 0 And InStr(rcol.Value, "L-Type") > 0 Then
                With rcol.EntireColumn.Cells
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=(today() - 120)"
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""Q"""
                    With .FormatConditions(1).Font
                        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End With
                    With .FormatConditions(2).Font
                        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End With
                End With
            End If
```

I hope this is what you need.